# Configuring imap account without smtp in thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap, smtp

I have an email account with an IMAP access but no SMTP.
I would like to add this account to thunderbird, but since I have no SMTP available, when I try to add the account I have the following error :

> Thunderbird failed to find the settings for your email account.

Is there a way to add an IMAP account without SMTP in thunderbird ? 
I have the latest version of Thunderbird (45.2) and I'm using Windows 8.1

Note : I have tested that the IMAP account is working with telnet.

Comment: IMAP is only for accessing your mail box. If you don't configure SMTP, you won't be able to send any messages only view inbox - are you sure this is your goal?

Comment: @MarekRost Yes, I don't want to send email from this account.

Comment: In that case try adding the account in Offline mode - otherwise Thunderbird attempts to check the account validity. It is common issue for it to get stuck and prevent you from continuing (and thus adding the account).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is behavior of Thunderbird is arguably poorly implemented, but you can add any account with any settings without contacting a server to verify those settings.

**TL;DR** -- After initial account verification failure, manually enter your email server settings (including any bogus ones) and press "Advanced config" when it appears. Then press "OK" once the account `Server Settings` are displayed. Your account is created.

### With Pictures!

First add an account via the normal process:

[image: Thunderbird Initial Account Setup Example]

Wait for Thunderbird to fail the settings or simply click "Manual config". Either of these options should bring you to a screen to enter account information manually. Enter any information you wish (use accurate information for the IMAP settings), but all fields should be filled out (i.e. make up an SMTP server and don't forget all the authentication stuff):

[image: Thunderbird Account Verification Failure Example]

Press "Advanced config" (you don't need to bother with "Re-test"
/"Done"/"Cancel") and the `Account Settings` screen should come up with `Server Settings` highlighted for the new account (which has miraculously been added without a single acknowledgement that this has occurred):

[image: Thunderbird Account Settings Example]

No fancy stuff, just press "OK" and you should now have a new account available in the main Thunderbird pane (at the bottom).

[image: Thunderbird Offline Manual Account Addition Successful Example]